# OLEDB connection to SQL connection?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, stack-overflow

How to change this oledb connection in to sql connection...
this is my sql connection line
[Data Source=SAKTHI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Payroll;User ID=sa;Password=***********]

```
 return @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Database\\PayrollSystem.mdb" + ";Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=junaldlagod";
```

Comment: This should be fairly straight-forward, have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i tried  return @"Data Source=SAKTHI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog =" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Database\\Payroll.dbo" + "; Integrated Security = True; User ID=sa;Password=***********";            but i got the error like login failed..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a proper "helper" to construct the string.  Not string concatentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx